# Obtain X Y coordinates from CvPoint

Tags: c, opencv

I have a code which finds contours in the image. This works fine and the contours found are stored and CvPoints are used to draw lines around the contours.

Now I want to set the ROI for the image
and I don't know how to refer to the X/Y points of the CvPoint to use.
The points pt all have defined values.

```
CvPoint *pt[4];
int ROIwidth = *pt[0].x - *pt[1].x;
```

This doesnt seem to work. I get errors saying the left of '.x' must have class/struct/union
How do I do it? Another article I found suggested that by adding the .x or .y should be able to do the trick..

Comment: Don't you think that you wrong in `*pt[0].x ` and it should be `pt[0]->x` or `(*pt[0]).x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your case can be explained by the fact that `*` has lower priority than `.` Thus you are trying to *dereference the integer*. That causes the issue.

Thus you should use:

```
pt[0]->x;
```

or

```
*(pt[0]).x;
```